# PHP + FFMPEG + S3. Transcode video directly between S3 buckets

Tags: php, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, transcoding

I have:

1. S3 INPUT bucket
2. S3 OUTPUT bucket
3. PHP
4. ffmpeg

Is it possible to read file directly from INPUT bucket → Transcode to another format → Save into OUTPUT bucket.

Please let me know manuals, libraries, frameworks, any stuff that helps to understand how to do it.
At least python realisations also welcome. At least at least some different language also OK.

Input file size may be more than 10Gb so writing whole file in RAM is undesirable. Some chunk-based way is preferable.

Output format is mostly `.mp4`, but input format may be ts video or image (`jpg`, `gif`, etc)

Looks like [PHP-FFmpeg-video-streaming](https://github.com/aminyazdanpanah/PHP-FFmpeg-video-streaming) fit to my task, but it can work only with web streaming formats.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, answering by myself:

```sh
aws s3 cp s3://bucketA/input.jpg - | ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -f jpeg_pipe -loop 1 -i - -c:v 'libx264' -r 29.97 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,setsar=1" -c:a aac -shortest -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4 /dev/stdout | aws s3 cp - s3://bucketB/output.mp4
```

Explanation:

1. Stream input file into stdout

```sh
aws s3 cp s3://bucketA/input.jpg -
```

2. Read input stream from stdin and stream it into stdout again

```sh
ffmpeg ... -f jpeg_pipe ... -i - ... -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov ... /dev/stdout
```

details:

2.1. `-f jpeg_pipe` input format must be `pipe` type. ffmpeg can detect type automatically so that is no necessary parameter
      2.2. `-i -` read from input (pipe)
      2.3. `-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov`  still don't understand what that [means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123272/ffmpeg-transmux-mpegts-to-mp4-gives-error-muxer-does-not-support-non-seekable), but can't create mp4 without this parameter. If somebody knows, please edit this place.
      2.4. `/dev/stdout` write output to stdout

3. Copy `stdin` stream to output bucket

```
aws s3 cp - s3://bucketB/output.mp4
```

But! I don't like this solution. Here is less control on situation and we don't able to raise/catch Exceptions.

I want to control stream by myself. Using PHP SDK S3 client looks smarter... So I still open for considerations.